# Different types of object in Interface

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have two methods with different signatures which I want to be declared in the `Interface`.

The two methods are as follows:

```
CBPeripheral[] GetDevicesConnected(string uuid); //iOS

List<string> GetDevicesConnected(); //Android
```

In the implementation, I have to explicitly implement the two methods. But Android does not accept `CBPeripheral` class. How can I bypass this in the implementation for `Android` ?

Comment: Using `#if` with platform specific definitions? If the binary is compiled separately for each platform

Comment: Like `#if __IOS__
       CBPeripheral[] GetConnectedDevices(string serviceUuid);
#endif` 

This you mean ?

Comment: Yes, those work fine if it’s separately compiled for each platform

Comment: Tell me something is this a pcl/scl or a shared project that you have

Comment: These methods are in a shared project which will be compiled as a NuGet package.

Comment: Okay, so what are you trying to achieve? Because if you want a shared code that would work for iOS and Android why would you use `CBPeripheral` which is a native iOS class!!

Comment: What can I use then ?

Comment: Check updated answer it might do what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `CBPeripheral` is a native iOS class you can never bypass this

**Update:** Might be possible that adding the if condition might do the trick for you.

```
#if __IOS__ 
CBPeripheral[] GetConnectedDevices(string serviceUuid);
#endif
#if __ANDROID__ 
List<string> GetDevicesConnected(); 
#endif
```

Comment: But I cannot implement this method in the `Android` class. And I strictly need to use the same interface definition.

Comment: So I don't need to implement `CBPeripheral[] GetConnectedDevices(string serviceUuid);` in the Android class.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is the whole point ain't it? Also, you if not this you can simply use a system object and bypass everything then cast into platforms as per your need

Comment: Yes brother. Thanks. 

Btw, have you ever implemented a drag and drop feature in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: If this worked mark it as right so that someone else can find the answer in the future also it would be better if you add another question for that so i can check what exactly are you looking for in detail